# Unable to create jar file from console and program don't work rigth after building with IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar, cmd, command

I try to learn how to inject bytecode in java with javassist and java agents so I started (http://appcrawler.com/wordpress/2013/01/02/simple-byte-code-injection-example-with-javassist/) << this tutorial I've copied the most of the code and read it to understand it that worked more or less.
But when the tutorial said I should create an jar file with this command

*`jar cvfm myAgent.jar mymanifest.txt SimpleMain.class SimpleTransformer.class`*

I tried to write this into my CMD console (hope that was rigth...) and it always tells me an error that he can't finde the command "Jar" so I googled the error and google said i should try

*`java -jar cvfm myAgent.jar mymanifest.txt SimpleMain.class SimpleTransformer.class`*

and this said "unable to acces jarfile cvfm"

Ok. After that I tried to create a jarfile with IntelliJ, but that didn't do what it should either. It don't even run the pre-main method so if the console command would work rigth it would be a nice start and if you guys can than help me do run the code rigth that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first command line was correct.  It's just that the jar exectuable was not on your path ( I'm going to assume you're on windows. )

You should first, make sure you have the JDK instead of the JRE installed, and follow the [oracle installation instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html).

Comment: If you just type "jar -version" it should spit out the version information for your installation.  If it can't find the jar command, but it can find the java command, and you're certain you have the JDK installed, then you have an incorrectly configured system and need to change your path.

Comment: Hmm oke and how do I change my path ? :D if u mean that windows classpath if checked this already

Comment: Not CLASS_PATH, but PATH.

echo %PATH% will show you the path you're currently using.

I haven't really used a windows machine for more then 5 minutes since 2004.  But a quick google takes you here (http://superuser.com/questions/317631/setting-path-in-windows-7-command-prompt ).

The oracle instructions I liked above include direction for various operating systems.

Comment: oke thanks first :D I'll check this but it will take some minutes because I have german OS so all has another name xd

Comment: No worries -- you're better off with a dependency managing build tool anyway ( maven/gradle/ant+ivy ).

Incidentally, if you're having PATH issues, it's worth fixing them anyway as they could come back to bite you down the line.